# How to get the img id for dynamically building IMG tags based on click like Share or Like or Comment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good Evening Everyone.

Background: I am getting list of images from a Mongo Database and then I am calling ajax once to load those data in to particular div.

Here I am building those img tags dynamically and then appending it to a div.

Now I am trying to get the img id based on user operation, lets say clicks on 'share button' for a particular img, then I have to get the image id, and then have to look search the DB with that image id.

My code after the ajax call is:

```
function showImages(imageList) {
    for ( var i = 0, len = imageList.length; i < len; i++) {
        var elem = document.createElement("img");
        elem.src = 'getImg/' + imageList[i][0] + '/' + imageList[i][1];
        elem.id = imageList[i][2];
        alert(elem.id);
        elem.height = '100';
        elem.width = '100';
        elem.alt = 'SPF HYD';
        /* $("a[id=shareImage]").click(function(){ 
            var qwerty = $("img", $(this).parent()).attr("id");
            alert('image id is after anchor by click...'+qwerty);
        }); */
        var image = document.getElementById("imageLoad");
        image.appendChild(elem);
    }
}
```

Could any one help me to get the image id onclick or any button trigger?

Comment: How the button and image related ? Each image have  it's button ? We really need  your help to solve this

Comment: I would recommend using event delegation for dynamically created elements. Just assign a jQuery event handler for the document delegated to the img tags, like so `$(document).on("click", "img", function(){ ... });`

Comment: your HTML structure?, just want to see the share button and the image html structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use addEventListener function to add an Event Listener to your dynamically created element.

```js
var div = document.getElementById("div");
var imgShare = document.createElement("img");
imgShare.src = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat-2/128/share-2-icon.png";
imgShare.id = "post002";
imgShare.addEventListener("click", share);
div.appendChild(imgShare);


var imgLike = document.createElement("img");
imgLike.src = "http://www.brandsoftheworld.com/sites/default/files/styles/logo-thumbnail/public/102011/like_icon.png?itok=nkurUMlZ";
imgLike.id = "post001";
imgLike.addEventListener("click", like);
div.appendChild(imgLike);

function share(e){
   alert("Share id:" + e.currentTarget.id);
}

function like(e){
   alert("like id:" + e.currentTarget.id);
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

JSFiddle [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/a7g4tbzr/)...

Comment: This answer doesn't address the key components of the question.

Comment: @Bishal, how to get image id (not shared pic or like pic) in shared or liked method. i have a list of images and each image has like and share, comment buttons. now i need to get the actual image id when i click on share option. i hope it provides good details to you.

Comment: @Bishal, You are awesome, Thanks brother. I sorted it out from your post. i can sleep happily now. :)

Comment: @SriniReddyM I am glad to know that it sorted out your problem. please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I threw a quick demo together to demonstrate what I meant. It's made possible using [jQuery event Delagation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```js
function showImages(imageList) {
    for ( var i = 0, len = imageList.length; i < len; i++) {
        var elem = document.createElement("img");
        elem.src = 'getImg/' + imageList[i][0] + '/' + imageList[i][1];
        elem.id = imageList[i][2];
        console.log(elem.id);
        elem.height = '100';
        elem.width = '100';
        elem.alt = 'SPF HYD';
        var image = document.getElementById("imageLoad");
        image.appendChild(elem);
    }
}

//The event handler is registered on the document object - the second argument here is the delegate, <img>
$(document).on("click", "img", function(e) { 
 alert($(this).attr("id"));
});

var imageList = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]; //These values are merely for testing
showImages(imageList);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imageLoad"></div>
```

Using Event Delegation is necessary here because your img tags are being dynamically generated, plus it's a lot cleaner to register one event handler for all img tags, rather than an event handler for each

Hope this helps

Comment: _if use clicks on 'share button' for perticular img_.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki My code outlines the process of event delegation - he can extrapolate what's necessary from there

Comment: @JonathanBrooks, how can i include share or like, comments option to that image.